# Writing Merge Sort in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, array, mergesort

I am learning programming online and currently watching CS50 lectures, in third lecture, professor introduces us to merge_sort though only through pseudo code, so I wanted someone to review my implementation and tell me where I can improve and what I possibly missed.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> void merge_sort(T m_array[], const size_t size) {
    using namespace std;
    if (size < 2)
        return;
    else if (size == 2) {
        if (m_array[0] > m_array[1])
            std::swap(m_array[0], m_array[1]); // no need for a new array
        return;
    }
    merge_sort(m_array, size / 2);
    merge_sort(m_array + size / 2,
               std::ceil(static_cast<double>(size) /
                         2) // for odd size, divison will have truncated value
                            // and recursion will left the the last array value
                            // for sorting, size%2==0?size/2:size/2+1
    );

    T *new_array = new T[size];
    size_t na_pos = 0;

    const T *array1 = m_array, *array2 = m_array + size / 2;

    const T *const array1end = m_array + size / 2, *const array2end =
                                                       m_array + size;

    while (1) {
        if (array1 == array1end)
            break;
        if (array2 == array2end)
            break;

        if (*array1 < *array2)
            new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
        else if (*array2 < *array1)
            new_array[na_pos++] = *array2++;
        else if (*array1 == *array2) {
            new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
            new_array[na_pos++] = *array2++;
        }
    }

    assert(array1 == array1end || array2 == array2end);

    while (array1 != array1end)
        new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
    while (array2 != array2end)
        new_array[na_pos++] = *array2++;
    assert(na_pos == size);

    for (na_pos = 0; na_pos < size; na_pos++)
        m_array[na_pos] = new_array[na_pos];

    delete[] new_array;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto limit = 10000;
    const auto size = 21;
    while (limit--) {
        vector<int> a;
        a.reserve(size);
        while (a.size() < size)
            a.push_back(rand() % 10000);
        merge_sort(a.data(), a.size());
        assert(std::is_sorted(a.begin(), a.end()));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `std::ceil(static_cast<double>(size) / 2` is a very long (and unclear) way to say `size - size/2`.
- No naked loops please. Each loop represents an important algorithm, and deserves a name. For example,

  ```
  while (array1 != array1end)
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
  ```

  wants to be `copy(new_array + na_pos, array1, array1_end);`, and you may reuse it at least 2 more times (and don't make it `void`: it has something interesting to return).

  Similarly, the merging loop represents a `merge` algorithm.
- The block

  ```
  if (*array1 < *array2)
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
  else if (*array2 < *array1)
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array2++;
  else if (*array1 == *array2) {
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array2++;
  }
  ```

  introduces a subtle problem. Here your algorithm may lose stability. If `array1` has two elements comparing equal, say `x1,x2`, and `array2` has an element `x3` which also compares equal to them, the final arrangement will be `x1, x3, x2`, whereas the stable sort should result in `x1, x2, x3`.

  The problem is easy to fix:

  ```
  if (*array1 <= *array2) {
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array1++;
  } else {
      new_array[na_pos++] = *array2++;
  }
  ```
- I strongly recommend to put the loop termination conditions where they belong:

  ```
  while ((array1 != array1end) && (array2 != array2end))
  ```

Comment: third point and it's fix took me some time to grasp, may be it's my English, but yeah very good catch, never caught that myself

Comment: @bluedragon I should've  said _don't copy from `array2` until you sure_. English is not my first language either.

Comment: if i use auto    lastNewAPos = std::copy(array1,array1end,new_array + na_pos);    std::copy(array2,array2end,lastNewAPos);
it's two seconds slower for 1000000 arrays

Answer (score 3):

## [Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

At least you didn’t do it in global scope; but you’ll have the same problems when a future version of the library adds names that cause ambiguities.

---

```
template <typename T> 
void merge_sort(T m_array[], const size_t size) {
```

[⧺I.13](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i13-do-not-pass-an-array-as-a-single-pointer) Do not pass an array as a single pointer.

If you *really* need to pass raw memory (only), use `gsl::span`.  But this is a template:  you should take begin/end iterators to *any* container.

---

```
T *new_array = new T[size];
```

[⧺C.149](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c149-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-avoid-forgetting-to-delete-objects-created-using-new) — no naked `new` or `delete`.

You should probably make this a `unique_ptr` as a drop-in replacement without otherwise changing the architecture.

---

```
        a.push_back(rand() % 10000);
```

`rand` is pretty bad.  Get used to using the proper random number facilities in the standard library.  You want a [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).